# R Mutating multiple columns with matching

Tags: r, dplyr

I am processing a large dataset adapted to my research. Suppose that I have 4 observations (records) and 5 columns as follows:

```
x <- data.frame("ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                "group1" = c("A", NA, "B", NA), 
                "group2" = c("B", "A", NA, "C"),
                "hours1" = c(3, NA, 5, NA),
                "hours2" = c(1, 2, NA, 5))

> x
ID group1 group2 hours1 hours2
 1      A      B      3      1
 2   <NA>      A     NA      2
 3      B   <NA>      5     NA
 4   <NA>      C     NA      5
```

The "group1" and "group2" are reference columns containing the character values of A, B, and C, and the last two columns, "hours1" and "hours2," are numeric indicating hours obviously.

The column "group1" is corresponding to the column "hours1"; likewise, "group2" is corresponding to "hours 2."

I want to create multiple columns according to the values, A, B, and C, of the reference columns matching to values of "hours1" and "hours2" as follows:

```
ID group1 group2 hours1 hours2  A  B  C
 1      A      B      3      1  3  1 NA
 2   <NA>      A     NA      2  2 NA NA
 3      B   <NA>      5     NA NA  5 NA
 4   <NA>      C     NA      5 NA NA  5
```

For example, ID 1 has A in "group1," corresponding to 3 in "hours1" which is found under the column "A." ID 3 has B in "group1," corresponding to 5 in "hours1" which is found under the columns "B." In "group 2," ID 4 has C, corresponding to 5 in hours2 which is found under column "C."

Is there a way to do it using R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to combine all the "hour" column in one column and "group" columns in another column. This can be done using `pivot_longer`. After that we can get data in wide format and join it with original data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, 
               names_to = c('.value'), 
               names_pattern = '(.*?)\\d+', 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = hours) %>%
  left_join(x, by = 'ID') %>%
  select(ID, starts_with('group'), starts_with('hour'), everything())

# A tibble: 4 x 8
#     ID group1 group2 hours1 hours2     A     B     C
#  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 A      B           3      1     3     1    NA
#2     2 NA     A          NA      2     2    NA    NA
#3     3 B      NA          5     NA    NA     5    NA
#4     4 NA     C          NA      5    NA    NA     5
```

---

For OP's dataset we can slightly modify the code to achieve the desired result.

```
zz %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, 
               names_to = c('.value'), 
               names_pattern = '(.*)_', 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(fu2a) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = fu2a, values_from = fu2b) %>%
  left_join(zz, by = 'id') %>%
  select(id, starts_with('fu2a'), starts_with('fu2b'), everything())
```

Comment: It worked on the example so I applied this script to my data with a slight modification (i.e., ID --> id; converted to data.frame) but an error message was followed: "Error: Can't combine `fu2a_1` <character> and `fu2b_1` <double>." If you don't mind, I will update the post with dput(df[1:7, 1:7]).

Comment: @toumai Change the `names_pattern` part in `pivot_longer` to `names_pattern = '(.*)_'` and keep everything else the same.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!!! One more question I have. Can the new columns be arranged in order?

Comment: They are now in [PERP 01]` `[PERP 03]`     `NA` `[PERP 05]` `[PERP 02]`... but wanted to be [PERP 01]` `[PERP 02]` `[PERP 03]`  ...

Comment: Yes, we can `arrange` them before using `pivot_wider`. Check the update in the answer.

Comment: The new columns are arranged in order. Thank you, truly appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `dplyr` could be done separating group and hours variables to compute the desired variables and then merge with the original `x`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
x <- data.frame("ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                "group1" = c("A", NA, "B", NA), 
                "group2" = c("B", "A", NA, "C"),
                "hours1" = c(3, NA, 5, NA),
                "hours2" = c(1, 2, NA, 5),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Reshape
x %>% 
  left_join(x %>% select(1:3) %>%
              pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
              group_by(ID) %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
              left_join(x %>% select(c(1,4:5)) %>%
                          pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
                          rename(name2=name,value2=value) %>%
                          group_by(ID) %>% mutate(id=1:n())) %>%
              filter(!is.na(value)) %>% select(ID,value,value2) %>%
              pivot_wider(names_from = value,values_from=value2))
```

Output:

```
  ID group1 group2 hours1 hours2  A  B  C
1  1      A      B      3      1  3  1 NA
2  2   <NA>      A     NA      2  2 NA NA
3  3      B   <NA>      5     NA NA  5 NA
4  4   <NA>      C     NA      5 NA NA  5
```